# My custom ThemeChangeEvent is changing my Theme only once

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am new to Flutter/dart. I am trying to understand Bloc structure of Flutter.
I am trying to change my Theme with using Bloc with a simple Weather App.

```
final _currentWeather = weatherState.weather;
final _weatherAbbr = _currentWeather.consolidatedWeather[0].weatherStateAbbr;
context.watch<ThemeBloc>().add(ThemeChangeEvent(weatherAbbr: _weatherAbbr));
```

I have added my event listener in my `BlocBuilder` after getting data from network provider. I have created my event/bloc/state classes which are working fine. When I pick a city it changes the Theme but latter it simply doesn't change. I debugged my code, when I change the city second time, my `bloc` class yields the result but my `state` class couldn't catch the result.

My `event` class :

```
  abstract class ThemeEvent extends Equatable {
  const ThemeEvent(List<String> list);

  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ThemeChangeEvent extends ThemeEvent {

  final String weatherAbbr;
  ThemeChangeEvent({@required this.weatherAbbr}) : super([weatherAbbr]);

}
```

My `bloc` class :

```
class ThemeBloc extends Bloc<ThemeEvent, ThemeState> {
  ThemeBloc() : super(ApplicationThemeLoaded(theme: ThemeData.light(), color: Colors.blue));

  @override
  Stream<ThemeState> mapEventToState(
    ThemeEvent event,
  ) async* {
    // TODO: implement mapEventToState

    ApplicationThemeLoaded applicationTheme;

    if (event is ThemeChangeEvent) {
      switch(event.weatherAbbr) {
        case "sn" :
        case "sl" :
        case "h" :
        case "t" :
        case "hc" :
          applicationTheme = ApplicationThemeLoaded(theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey), color: Colors.grey);
          break;

        case "hr" :
        case "lr" :
        case "s" :
          applicationTheme = ApplicationThemeLoaded(theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.indigoAccent), color: Colors.indigo);
          break;

        case "lc" :
        case "c" :
          applicationTheme = ApplicationThemeLoaded(theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.orangeAccent), color: Colors.yellow);
          break;
      }
      yield applicationTheme;
    }
  }
}
```

My `state` class :

```
abstract class ThemeState extends Equatable {
  const ThemeState(List<Object> list);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ApplicationThemeLoaded extends ThemeState {

  final ThemeData theme;
  final MaterialColor color;

  ApplicationThemeLoaded({@required this.theme, @required this.color}) : super([theme, color]);
}
```

And this is my `main.dart` class where I am trying to change my Theme :

```
void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(BlocProvider<ThemeBloc>(
    create: (context) => ThemeBloc(),
    child: MyApp(),));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ThemeBloc, ThemeState>(
      builder: (context, ThemeState themeState) =>
      MaterialApp(
        title: 'Weather App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: (themeState as ApplicationThemeLoaded).theme,
        home: BlocProvider<WeatherBloc>(
            create: (context) => WeatherBloc(),
            child: WeatherApp()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theme` and `color` of your `ApplicationThemeLoaded` class should be checked for comparison.

Include them in `props`:

```
class ApplicationThemeLoaded extends ThemeState {

  final ThemeData theme;
  final MaterialColor color;

  ApplicationThemeLoaded({@required this.theme, @required this.color}) : super([theme, color]);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [theme,color];
}
```

This should help telling that the current state is different from the previous one, thus triggering the state update.